# 405 Method Not Allowed POST Laravel

Tags: php, web-services, laravel

I have a laravel api that I'm trying to run a custom artisan command to process a transaction. The api is suppose to check for pending transactions in our merchant database and post them in our transaction database.
I get the following error:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]
  Client error: `POST http://paycentral.mymarket.com/transactions/bulk` resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed` response:
  {"error":{"message":"405 Method Not Allowed","status_code":405,"debug":{"line":446,"file":"\/var\/www\/vhosts\/maindomai (truncated...)
```

The API I'm using is located at api.mymarket.com. Searching for errors like this has me believing it's a CORS-related issue. I'm using laravel-cors and added Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to the .htaccess in both the public folder for api.mymarket.com and paycentral.mymarket.com. The error is still persisting though. Is there any other possible workaround? We are currently using plesk for our hosting services.

UPDATE: I tried doing a preflight request in the pay subdomain
Origin: api.mymarket.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: MM

It returned a 500 Internal Error which is progress I guess.

UPDATE Here is the routes.php for paycentral. The cors-library is registered in the app.php.

paycentral routes.php

```
<?php

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

// all routes are protected by the Authenticate middleware which makes sure     the client
// is authenticated as *somebody* - each resource is further protected by  the authorization
// policies in the App\Api\V1\Policies files to limit the method calls by which client
// type is attempting to access the resource - these must be mapped in the     AuthServiceProvider
$api->group([
    'version' => 'v1',
    'namespace' => 'App\Api\V1\Controllers',
    'middleware' => 'auth' // use the Authenticate middleware
], function($api) {

/*
     * partial CRUD resource routes
     */

    $api->get('transactions/{id}', 'TransactionController@show');
    $api->post('transactions', 'TransactionController@store');
    $api->put('transactions/{id}', 'TransactionController@update');
    $api->post('transactions/bulk', 'TransactionController@store_bulk');
    $api->post('transactions/get_updates',  'TransactionController@get_updates');
```

Comment: are you sure of the route definition in the `route.php`??

Comment: Did you add the middleware from `laravel-cors` library to all your routes or that specific route? Also, it may not be CORS issue at all, as it could give you a pre-flight request error.

Comment: If you are making a curl request it shouldn't have anything to do with CORS. CORS is only used if you make a cross origin request aka different domains.

Comment: They are two different sub-domains though which I thought also applied the same.

Comment: Show us the route definition for `http://paycentral.mymarket.com/transactions/bulk` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was an issue with one of the routes not pointing to transactions/bulk. The previous developer made undocumented changes to a couple files without following our version control methods so the production branch was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your route is defined well in the routes.php, and that everything else is fine. Then you may try adding the following line in your `filters.php`

```
App::before(function ($request) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
}
```

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.2 and don't have a filters.php. I tried going through the steps for onvardgmbh/laravel-filters and had no luck.

Comment: ok, can you add the line that specifies the header somewhere before the app starts (for debugging only) to see if this helps or we should go in different direction !